# How to group ans sort posts in wordpress according to date?

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, custom-taxonomy

I have the following code that sorts the posts by title. See attached screenshot.

desired result [image: This is what i want]

This is what i am getting right now

[image: This is what I am getting rt now]

What I want is group the posts together i.e posts with Date as December should come under December and those with November should be under november as so on. Both images attached.

I need some tweaks in the code which is below.

```
                 <div class="margin-top" style="margin-top: 20px;">
                <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

                    <div class="articles-list">

                        <?php do_action( 'presscore_before_loop' ); ?>

                        <?php update_post_thumbnail_cache(); ?>

                                <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                                <?php 

  $start=0;
  $venue = basename(parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH));

  if (isset($venue) && !empty($venue)) {
      global $post;
      $venue_a = get_term_by('slug',$venue, 'venues');
      for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
        $key = get_post_meta($post->ID,'sub_seminars_'.$i.'_venue',true);

        if($venue_a->name == $key ){
          $ref = get_post_meta($post->ID,'sub_seminars_'.$i.'_ref',true); 
          $ven_label = get_post_meta($post->ID,'sub_seminars_'.$i.'_venue',true);   
          $start_date = get_post_meta($post->ID,'sub_seminars_'.$i.'_start_date',true);   
          $end_date = get_post_meta($post->ID,'sub_seminars_'.$i.'_end_date',true);   
          $fees = get_post_meta($post->ID,'sub_seminars_'.$i.'_fees',true); 
          $start =1;
          break;
        }
      }
  }


    ?>

                <table class="gry-bkgrnd-sec" style=" border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;">
                     <tbody>
                          <?php if( have_rows('sub_seminars') ): ?>
                          <?php while ( have_rows('sub_seminars') ) : the_row();

                            ?>
                                <tr style="background-color: #50619a">
                                    <td style="width: 100px; color: #fff;">Reference</td>
                                    <td style="width: 400px; color: #fff;">Title</td>
                                    <td style="width: 200px; color: #fff;">Dates</td>
                                    <td style="width: 100px; color: #fff;">Venue</td>
                                     <td style="width: 100px; color: #fff;">Fees</td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                              <td style="width: 200px;"><?php the_sub_field('ref'); ?></td>
                                <td style="width: 400px;">                 


                                   <a style=" color: #044970;" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php echo the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ); ?>" rel="bookmark">
                                       <?php the_title(); ?></a><?php if (get_field('seminar_sub_title')) : ?>
                                       <a style=" color: #044970;" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark">
                                           <?php the_field('seminar_sub_title'); ?><?php endif; ?></a>

                              </td>

                              <td>


                             <?php
                             if(date("m", strtotime($start_date)) != date("m", strtotime($end_date)))
                             {
                             echo date("d M", strtotime($start_date)).' - '.date("d M", strtotime($end_date));
                             }
                             else
                             {
                             echo date("d", strtotime($start_date)).' - '.date("d M", strtotime($end_date));

                             }
                             ?>


                              </td>

                              <td style="width: 45px;">
                              <?php echo $ven_label; ?>
                              </td>

                               <td style="width: 45px;">
                                   <?php  echo $fees; ?>
                               </td>

                               </tr>


                               <?php break; ?>
                               <?php endwhile; ?>
                               <?php endif; ?>

                               </tbody>
                               </table>

                        <?php endwhile; ?>

                        <?php do_action( 'presscore_after_loop' ); ?>

                    </div>

                    <?php dt_paginator(); ?>

                <?php else : ?>

                    <?php get_template_part( 'no-results', 'blog' ); ?>

                <?php endif; ?>

     </div>
```

The venues shown is a custom taxonomy created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code I wrote t fix the above problem

```
<?php
$archive_data = get_queried_object();
//echo '<pre>';print_r( $archive_data );
$archiveId = $archive_data->term_id;
$categroy_name =  $archive_data->slug;
$seminar_venue = $archive_data->name;
$subseminars_found = euromatech_search_subseminars( '', $archive_data->slug, '');
 if(!empty($subseminars_found)){
    foreach($subseminars_found as $month => $day){
        ?>
        <div class="dec-box">
            <h3 class="year-title"><?php echo date('M Y', $month); ?></h3>
            <div class="register-table table-sec">
                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr class="background-g">
                        <th class="left-td seminar-title-header">Program Title</th>
                        <th class="text-center"><?php echo date('Y', $month); ?> Dates</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Venues</th>
                    </tr>
                    <?php

                    foreach($day as $subseminars){
                        foreach($subseminars as $subseminar) {

                            ?>

                            <tr>
                                <td class="left-td"><a href="<?php the_permalink($subseminar['seminarID']); ?>">
                                        <?php echo get_the_title($subseminar['seminarID']); ?> <?php if (get_field('seminar_sub_title', $subseminar['seminarID'])) : ?><?php echo get_field('seminar_sub_title', $subseminar['seminarID']); ?><?php endif; ?></a></td>
                                <td class="date-year text-center"><?php echo date('d M', strtotime($subseminar['start_date'])) . ' - ' . date('d M', strtotime($subseminar['end_date'])); ?></td>
                                <td class="text-center"><?php echo esc_html($subseminar['venue_name']); ?></td>
                            </tr>

                            <?php                          
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php
    }

} 

else {

    echo '<h4>No Upcoming Seminars found</h4>';
    echo '<p>For further information on forthcoming events in this region, please contact <a href="mailto:',ot_get_option('email_address', ''),'">',ot_get_option('email_address', ''),'</a></p>';
}

?>
```

Hope it Helps someone else.